# Erro jQuery + AngularJS + Materialize CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, materialize

Tenho o seguinte procedimento no meu controller do angular:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  angular.element('.button-collapse').sideNav();
  angular.element('.parallax').parallax();
});
```

Estou iniciando esses componentes do materialize css. Quando entro a primeira vez nessa página está tudo Ok, porém caso eu clique em algum link dentro do site que me redireciona para a página, ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at r.fn.load (localhost:8080/assets/libs/jquery-3.1.0.min.js:4:18716)
    at HTMLImageElement.<anonymous> (localhost:8080/assets/libs/materialize.min.js:8:4380)
    at Function.each (localhost:8080/assets/libs/jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2:2815)
    at r.each (localhost:8080/assets/libs/jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2:1003)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (localhost:8080/assets/libs/materialize.min.js:8:4341)
    at Function.each (localhost:8080/assets/libs/jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2:2815)
    at r.each (localhost:8080/assets/libs/jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2:1003)
    at r.a.fn.parallax (localhost:8080/assets/libs/materialize.min.js:8:3872)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (localhost:8080/assets/js/app.js:25:36)
    at j (localhost:8080/assets/libs/jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2:29568) undefined
```

Não consegui resolve-lo..estou iniciando nessa plataforma.. alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, o elemento que você está tentando selecionar não existe no contexto em que você está. Se puder, posta um pouco mais de código pra eu entender melhor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`angular.element` não consegue fazer css-selectors newm por `tagname` nem por `.classname`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#!) para fazeres essa selecção tens duas hipoteses:

- a) Faz a inclusão do jQuery *primeiro* que o Angular, assim o `angular.element` fica um alias para o `$`
- b) usa, como diz nas docs, `document.querySelectorAll()`

Comment: Eu acho que você está equivocado quando fala que o angular.element não faz seleção de elementos através do nome da classe. Ele faz sim, inclusive já vi em um sistema no meu trabalho.